# How to hide an included in header page from some specific pages in my website?

Tags: php, include, smarty

I have a search bar included in header :

```
{include file="quick-search.html"}
```

and of course the header contains another things such the logo and sign-in/sign-up buttons

So since the header is included everywhere I want to do some exceptions like detail page (the search bar means nothing there) and of course keep the header (sign-in/sign-up buttons and logo).

So is is there a way to un-include an included page in a specific page?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

If you have something in your code that indicates what the current page is then wrapping your `{include}` in an `if` statement should work. Something like the following:

```
{if $page !== 'details'}
    {include file="quick-search.html"}
{/if}
```

The above would indicate to include the search bar on all pages except 'details' page.

Comment: My comment might seem stupid but is the $page a part of smarty? 
The script I use for my website I bought it. I am not really good at web development I only have some few concepts and I understood your idea but still I don't know how to add this if statement and what are the variables I should use...

Comment: @yeknissay No it wouldn't be part of Smarty. It's something your app would track, most likely based on a URL parameter, ie `$smarty->assign('page', $_GET['page']);` if the page in the URL was `index.php?page=details`.

Comment: Okay thank you so much I'll try to find a solution based on your comment. 
Thank you again

Comment: I put the search bar on a div and I hide it with css... Maybe it's not the best solution but it worked x)